# scrolling of website is slow when large amount of data/content is loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, scroll

When on my website large amount of data like picture and gallery slider and data along with animation is being loaded it causes the scrolling of the page slow. when I try to scroll the page through the arrow keys the scrolling becomes almost zero with lags between them.
all the javascript files and css are being loaded from cdn links.
is there any specific reason why it is getting slow scrolling. I have used AngularJS.

Comment: will you please describe configuration of your pc ?

Comment: & would you mind to send a link to your page?

Comment: system configuration:
OS : X El Capitan version 10.11.4
macbookAir (13 inch, Early 2014)
Processor 1.4Ghz Intel Core i5
Memory 4GB 1600 MHz DDR3
Graphics Intel HD Graphics 5000 1536 MB

Comment: link cannot be provided because it is for internal purpose of the team with username and password login

Comment: would you please tell us about CMS that is it develop on wordpress or any other?

Comment: bootstrap and angular js is used

Answer (score 0):

This is just a guess, but you need to optimize all your photos for whatever size you are displaying it for because they are likely too large. You can use this link to create your new image files:

http://optimizilla.com/

Comment: images are of compressed size of 100 - 200kb only

Answer (score 0):

Using the one time binding with angular and increasing the gallery sliding time and there are many way in which angular can be optimised. 
https://www.binpress.com/tutorial/speeding-up-angular-js-with-simple-optimizations/135

It helped in my case